# Alias method chain with method not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, alias-method-chain

I have a module that gets included inside an Rails Observer.

The purpose is:

- Call on `after_save` and `after_update` a method named `check_integrity`
- Call `check_integrity` at the end of `after_save` or/and `after_update`if defined in the Observer.

**So in short it should always call `check_integrity`.**

I tried something that looks like the following code:

```
module IntegrityObserver
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    alias_method_chain :after_save,   :check_integrity
    alias_method_chain :after_update, :check_integrity
  end

  def check_integrity
    # do something
  end
end

class UserObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  include IntegrityObserver

  def after_save(object)
    # do something
  end
end
```

But it raise an error: `activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in alias_method': undefined method after_update' for class TaskObserver' (NameError)`

Someone has any idea how I can do what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: is the `include CacheObserver` line intended to be `include IntegrityObserver`? Where does TaskObserver come into it? Does including the modules *after* the `after_save` definition help matters?

Comment: Thanks I fixed it @x1a4, including after the after_save will work but not when the method is not defined

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord already provides observer functionality to monitor the lifecycle of your models. Here is how you can register a generic observer which responds to more than one model:

```
class AuditObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :account, :balance

  def after_update(record)
    AuditTrail.new(record, "UPDATED")
  end
end
```

In your config/application.rb file:

```
config.active_record.observers = :audit_observer
```

Check out more examples [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html).

Answer (score 1):

alias_method_chain doesn't work that way. If you define something like:

```
alias_method_chain :after_save,   :check_integrity
```

you'll have to define the following method:

```
def after_save_with_check_integrity(*args)
  # do something
  # you can call the original after_save by calling:
  # after_save_without_check_integrity(*args)
end
```

just be aware that the alias_method_chain use is in most cases considered a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Not like models, observers don't have predefined callback methods, such as after_save, after_update. So you got an "undefined method" error.

You may do it like this,

```
module IntegrityObserver
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def after_save(record)
    check_integrity
  end

  def after_update(record)
    check_integrity
  end

  def check_integrity
    # do something
  end
end
```